# Firewall on. I blocked IP 93.184.220.29 with PF but it still popsup in netstat -n

Tags: network, security, firewall

The firewall is on. I blocked IP 93.184.220.29 with PF but it still popsup in `netstat -n.`
How is that possible?

```
jen:~ jen$ sudo pfctl -t blockedips -T show
Password:
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
   93.184.220.29
```

Output of

```
netstat -n

tcp4       0      0  192.168.2.4.51402      93.184.220.29.80       ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.2.4.51401      93.184.220.29.80       ESTABLISHED
```

Output of

```
 sudo pfctl -s all
Password:
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
TRANSLATION RULES:
nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all

FILTER RULES:
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple/*" all
block drop quick on ALL proto tcp from any to any port = 80
block drop quick on ALL proto udp from any to any port = 80

DUMMYNET RULES:
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*" all
```

Output of:

```
sudo pfctl -vvv -s all
Password:
No ALTQ support in kernel
ALTQ related functions disabled
TRANSLATION RULES:
@0 nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 179894    Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@0 rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 574091    Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]

FILTER RULES:
@0 scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 1133714   Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@0 anchor "com.apple/*" all
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 574091    Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@1 block drop inet from any to 93.184.220.29
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 574091    Packets: 812       Bytes: 51968       States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@2 block drop inet from any to 93.184.220.70
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 573678    Packets: 210       Bytes: 13152       States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@3 block drop quick on ALL proto tcp from any to any port = 80
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 574091    Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
@4 block drop quick on ALL proto tcp from any to any port = 53
  [ Owner : nil          Priority : 0     ]
  [ Evaluations: 0         Packets: 0         Bytes: 0           States: 0     ]
  [ Inserted: uid 0 pid 68 ]
```

Comment: The table `blockedips` doesn't seem to be blocking that IP address, which is the output of `sudo pfctl -s all` ?

Comment: I edited and added the output of sudo pfctl -s all

Comment: Thanks jennifer, the output doesn't display any table named `blockedips`, I'd expect to see such a table listed (similar to this: `block drop on en1 from <badhosts> to any`). Could it be that the table is not active? At the end of the ouput of `sudo pfctl -s all`, do you see a `TABLES` section that lists `badblocks`? Could you add the output of `sudo pfctl -T test 93.184.220.291`?

Comment: Someone stole your code from StackOverflow, put it on their own site and didn't even link back here.
[Stolen Code](https://itectec.com/askdifferent/firewall-on-i-blocked-ip-93-184-220-29-with-pf-but-it-still-popsup-in-netstat-n/)

Comment: Thank you @themrvideouser - Here is how to handle sites that don’t honor the license here - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/

Answer (score 4):

I made a mistake:

Blocking in the IP is archieved via:

Inserting

```
block drop inet from any to 93.184.220.29
block drop inet from any to 93.184.220.70
```

In

```
 sudo nano /etc/pf.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

My friend, your netstat tells me your machine is connected to the usual webserver port on the foreign host.  You likely have running in the background a web browser open to that host.

Next, the syntax of your filter rules does not reflect well your intent.  Your elected default for a policy will affect behavior, in conjunction to rulesets.  Additionally, a thorough assessment can not be had without the full pf.conf and any anchor files or includes...  Better still if you included the output of

```
sudo pfctl -vvv -s all
```

if memory serves me well...

The quick and dirty...

```
block in
block out

block in quick all from x.x.x.x to any
block out quick all from any to x.x.x.x
```

...but better if these were evaluated in context of the whole config.

F.

Comment: I added the output of sudo pfctl -vvv -s all. I now see that pf is not blocking the ports that I want it to block

Comment: @jenniferruurs I hope that helped.  Take care,